# What is the reason one sql server process needs "RangeS-U" lock though it has "X" lock on the same table-key

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework-6, database-deadlocks

I am looking for a fix to one deadlock issue, using Entity Framework 6.1, and set READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT ISOLATION ON for SQL Server database.

Below image is SQL profiler Deadlock graph, let me know if I should provide any other details which is needed to get into the issue.

In image below...

CustomerOrder table is a mapping table (Customerid, OrderId), and has a composite PK (Customerid, OrderId) with unique non-clustered index

[image]

Comment: That visualization is misleading and leaves out a lot of information. It's a good idea to get accustomed to reading the actual XML data describing the deadlock event (that includes the queries as well).

Answer (score 0):

X is not a range mode. It will only cover one key, not a range. It's therefore not sufficient for whatever query you are running.

Since you're using snapshot isolation I assume your DML statements are conflicting in some ware. Range locks are common for FK checks. Hope this helps you.

Consider posting the conflicting statements and all other helpful information you have.